# .NET Core Entity Framework throws Invalid object name when accessed as entity, but works with SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working with Entity Framework Core, v6.2. I'm getting an error

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Cdef.CellDefinition'

when I try to access the `DbSet` directly, but using the same `DbContext` object, I can query the object directly using the `FromSql` command.

I've seen other answers saying to modify the conventions to remove `PluralizingTableNameConvention`, however since I'm doing a `EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext` that `ModelBuilder` does not have that option, and I don't see any evidence it is try to access a Pluralized name.

My entity is setup like:

```
[Table("Cdef.CellDefinition")]
public partial class CellDefinition
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And my `DbContext` is like:

```
public class CDefContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public virtual Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<CellDefinition> CellDefinition { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I try to access the object as an entity directly, I get an error:

> Invalid Object Name

but if I issue the SQL with the same object name it works properly.

```
// This fails with Invalid Object Name
return cDefContext.CellDefinition.ToList();

// This succeeds
return cDefContext.CellDefinition.FromSql("select * from CDef.CellDefinition").ToList()
```

Comment: Just a side note: the **EF Core** is currently at version 2.1 (which 2.2 in the works) - version 6.2 belongs to the "legacy" (**non** .NET Core) version of EF .....

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution.  You can't put the schema in the table name.

```
//This Does NOT work
[Table("Cdef.CellDefinition")]
public partial class CellDefinition{}


//But this DOES work
[Table("CellDefinition",Schema = "Cdef")]
public partial class CellDefinition{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me a lot!